# Multi agent system vs Cellular Automata

Tags: system, agent, cellular-automata

Could someone describe the difference between MAS and CA? Is MAS derived from CA or do they share similar principles, or are they completely different entities that are used together to simulate complex behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the link bewlo to get the more details about the topic you are referring to: 
http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4471-0709-5_4#

Comment: I have read this paper, it incorporates both multi agent and cellular automata but in larger domain they use multi agent systems, in which they model the agent and the environment, question is what is the advantage compared to the previous